# Auto centering list item/image 100% page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, image-gallery

basically, what i am trying to achieve is the following layout;

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8256/8746793625_d3fed90c54_b.jpg

I have tried using tables, but could not get the images to 100% of the page height.
I have tried crating an unordered list with display:inline and the images resized correctly, but I could not 'centre' on the "main" or second item in my list.

I am limited by the fact that I can't specify the dimension's of the images.
I would like to stick to CSS of possible, unless maybe there is a way of testing the window size with Jquery and feeding that in somehow? (im pretty new to this)

I'm all out of ideas, can anyone help?!?!

Cheers!

This is as close as I got;

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; top:0; left:0;">

    <table style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; top:0; left:0; text-align:center;    white-space: nowrap;    overflow:hidden;">

            <td style="width:20%" ><img style="position:relative;width:auto;max-height:100%" src="http://shellsuitzombie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Brad-Rose-I-never-finish-anything.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:60%" ><img style="position:relative;width:auto;max-height:100%" src="http://shellsuitzombie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Brad-Rose-I-never-finish-anything.jpg"></td>
            <td style="width:20%" ><img style="position:relative;width:auto;max-height:100%" src="http://shellsuitzombie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Brad-Rose-I-never-finish-anything.jpg"></td>


</tr></table></div></body>
```

Comment: do you want to get the image size to 100% of the view or a div to that size?

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/sAHMu/)???

Comment: @Ashley: can you add your code or use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @SpYk3HH   sort of, I just need to add images and make them max-height:100%;width:auto

Answer (score 5):

**The problem should be in your arrangement of tables**
will you please check out the table and where you sending your upload file . weather is calling the jQuery or not your jquery function is called or not and put the image width and height to 100% and if you give me your site link I will do for you.